# Data length in JSON response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

the output of the code below is this:

```
[{"user_name":"Maria","user_surname":"Dominguez"},{"user_name":"Celia","user_surname":"Paris"}]
95
```

I expected the length be 2. Any explanation?

```
$.get(
    "http://myfirm.local/school/view-more-users",
    {"type": user_type, "school_id": school_id, "offset": offset},
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        ,  
    "json"
);
```

Javier

Comment: using $.each to deal with it, you don't need to know how many elements I think.

Answer (score 4):

```
data= JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.length);
```

OR

```
data= $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data.length);
```

Comment: this doesn't work... data is object and data.length is undefined

Answer (score 1):

The console.log will output you 95 because it interprets your **data** object as a string which in fact has exactly 95 characters.

Answer (score 0):

because you are looking at the length of string. Try parsing it in JSoN object and see the length

```
$.parseJSON(data)
```